# Can I position custom page size document on standard paper and plan to cut?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2010

I'd like to print a booklet using MS word 2010, by using one of the 2 options:

1. Print double-sided sheets (2 pages on one sheet)
2. Print double-sided foldable sheets (4 pages on one sheet)

In either case, I would cut each sheet and bind the booklet manually.
I don't mind to manually handle the printing order of pages, but I'm having hard time to position a single page (smaller than standard) on an A4 page. Margins are really small, and I would like to position the page so all the content is really printed, e.g. centered on the paper.

Any suggestions?

Comment: From what I see, Word doesn't make a difference between page and paper, so it's Margins/Pages/Multiple Pages setting won't work after my document is created with custom PAPER size.

Answer (score 0):

As I feared - you can't do that. The best approximation was to print to PDF (using PrimoPDF or such), making sure that paper size of printer equals my custom paper size, to avoid scaling that breaks the deal by failing to maintain original/required dimensions.

After that, print from Adobe Reader, choosing scaling mode to "None" (to avoid changing page size) and choosing "Auto rotate and center" to make sure that the page is centered on paper to avoid margin cropping of content, and make sure that both sides will fit on the sheet after cutting.

If only there was the option to print crop marks, it'd be great, but it's also fine like this.